# How to create new column in dataframe based on condition from other dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"DEPTH":[0.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5],
                     "POROSITY":[10, 22, 15, 30, 20],
                     "WELL":"well 1"})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({"Well":"well 1",
                    "Marker":["Fm 1","Fm 2"],
                    "Depth":[0.7, 1.7]})
```

Hello everyone. I have two dataframes and I would like to create a new column on df1, for example: df1["FORMATIONS"], with information from df2["Marker"] values based on depth limits from df2["Depth"] and df1["DEPTH"].

So, for example, if df2["Depth"] = 1.7, then all samples in df1 with df1["DEPTH"] > 1.7 should be labelled as "Fm 2" in this new column df1["FORMATIONS"].

And the final dataframe df1 should look like this:

```
DEPTH   POROSITY   WELL   FORMATIONS
0.5     10        well 1     nan
1       22        well 1     Fm 1
1.5     15        well 1     Fm 1
2       30        well 1     Fm 2
2.5     20        well 1     Fm 2
```

Anyone could help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`pandas.merge_asof`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html):

*NB. the columns used for the merge need to be sorted first*

```
pd.merge_asof(df1,
              df2[['Marker', 'Depth']].rename(columns={'Marker': 'Formations'}),
              left_on='DEPTH', right_on='Depth')
```

output:

```
   DEPTH  POROSITY    WELL Formations  Depth
0    0.5        10  well 1        NaN    NaN
1    1.0        22  well 1       Fm 1    0.7
2    1.5        15  well 1       Fm 1    0.7
3    2.0        30  well 1       Fm 2    1.7
4    2.5        20  well 1       Fm 2    1.7
```

Answer (score 2):

What you're doing here is transforming *continuous data* into *categorical data*. There are many ways to do this with `pandas`, but one of the better known ways is using [`pandas.cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.cut.html).

When specifying the `bins` argument, you need to add `float(inf)` to the end of the list, to represent that the last bin goes to infinity.

```
df1["FORMATIONS"] = pd.cut(df1.DEPTH, list(df2.Depth) + [float('inf')], labels=df2.Marker)
```

`df1` will now be:

[image: Table of results]